# Open calendar from Swift app

Tags: swift, events, calendar

How can I open a calendar from Swift app (when pressing a button for example)? Or is there a way to embed a calendar in a view controller in the app?
I want to avoid using external calendars programmed by others. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can open the Calendar app by using the url scheme `calshow://`:

Swift 3+

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "calshow://") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Swift 2 and below

```swift
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "calshow://")!)
```

With EventKit, you can implement your self a calendar. You should read [Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Apple site.

Comment: I could not find a calendar programming guide for Swift, only for Objective-C. I prefer Swift.

Comment: You can translate your self the code into swift. Or take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/mchirico/d072c4e38bda61040f91#file-cal-swift

Comment: Can we open default reminder like  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "calshow://")!) ?

Comment: @Hoa Thank you for the answer, made my day!

Answer (score 2):

**openURL Deprecated in iOS10**

*From Apple’s guide to [What’s New](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html) in iOS in the section on UIKit:*

> The new UIApplication method openURL:options:completionHandler:, which
>   is executed asynchronously and calls the specified completion handler
>   on the main queue (this method replaces openURL:).

**Swift 3**

```
func open(scheme: String) {
  if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
        completionHandler: {
          (success) in
           print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
       })
    } else {
      let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
      print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
    }
  }
}

// Typical usage
open(scheme: "calshow://")
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)openScheme:(NSString *)scheme {
  UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:scheme];

  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    [application openURL:URL options:@{}
       completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
    }];
  } else {
    BOOL success = [application openURL:URL];
    NSLog(@"Open %@: %d",scheme,success);
  }
}

// Typical usage
[self openScheme:@"calshow://"];
```

**Note:-** *Don't forgot to add privacy usage description in your info.plist file.,if you are trying to open any system app then in iOS 10+ you need to specify privacy usage description in your info.plist file else your app get crash.*

Answer (score 1):

As HoaParis already mentioned, you can call the calendar by using the `openURL` method.

There is no embedded calendar by apple by default but you could check out other calendars for example the open-source one [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) which is available at github. So you could either use it in your project or check how the developer has coded the calendar.